# Maximum boundary edges amount of union of rectangles

Tags: computational-geometry, correctness-proof

I've read that the maximum boundary edges amount of union of $n$ rectangles, named $p$, is bounded by

> $p \leq n^2 + 4n$

I tried to prove this by induction, but it's seems too difficult to me, can anyone help me with the proof? thanks.

an induction try:
$n = 1$, $p = 4 \leq 1^2 + 4$ is clear.
assume when $n = m$, $p \leq m^2 + 4m$ is correct
when $n = m + 1$, 
 $p <= m^2 + 4m + (boundary\ egdes\ generate\ by\ the\ m+1 th\ rectangle)$ 
$......\ (after\ some\ steps)$

 $p \leq m^2 + 2m + 1 + 4m + 4$

 $p \leq (m+1)^2 + 4(m+1)$ 
  end of proof 
here is an example of boundary edges(red line part) [image: example] 
can draw a $p = n^2+4n$ case if $n$ is even (upper bound seems not tight when $n$ is odd) [image: example]
origin claim is here (page 8 line 21) if needed [link](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0196677480900115/1-s2.0-0196677480900115-main.pdf?_tid=f72fdac2-4e17-4339-8282-ee879b517953&acdnat=1528206180_5da97547a0651a05f7514dd9604b03fd)

(p.s. It's first time I post a question, I apologize if it's hard too read)

Comment: I would try to find a class of (ideally simple) rectangle arrangements that I can prove always achieves the maximum possible number of edges for any given number of rectangles: If you can find such a class, then you only need to prove that generating the next arrangement *in this sequence* meets the $n^2 + 4n$ bound (since you will have already shown that every other arrangement uses at most that many).  It also might help here to proceed "2 steps at a time" (one horizontal, one vertical) -- this may require 2 separate induction arguments for odd-sized and even-sized instances.

Comment: The strategy that I know for proving the first part is essentially to show that, given any arrangement of rectangles, you can apply a series of moves (repositionings and/or resizings) to them that (a) transforms them into an arrangement in the target class while (b) never decreasing the number of boundary edges.